# Toilet bowl cleaner container distorts flushing action

Tags: toilet

I placed a toilet bowl cleaner container (jar) into the tank per the instructions. Normally, previously, when flushed the water would completely empty the bowl. Now it fills up and drains but does not do the final emptying. It does drain down to the normal level after a bit. I did not expect there to be a change in the functionality of flushing.

I have adjusted the level in the tank so that there is the maximum fill. The photo shows where the overflow point is. It now fills completely to the overflow. This has not made the flush work as it did before.

I assume the volume of the jar has reduced the amount of water that is contained in the tank and that a solution involves increasing the amount that can be held even with the jar inside the tank.

[image: tank with overflow point indicated]

I am looking for a change that will restore the previous flushing results and keeping the new cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

1. Step one - does removing the jar solve the problem?
2. Step two - can the jar be placed differently in the tank, and if so,
   does the problem recur?

It's probably not the volume, and it may simply be the case that this type of toilet cleaner is not compatible with the hydraulics of your toilet tank (which can be quite sophisticated in modern low-flush toilets, so adding an obstacle that might not have bothered an old 5 gallons-per-flush toilet may simply no longer be an option - in which case you need to clean the toilet another way...)

Comment: If the jar is close to the flapper it will affect the efficiency of water flowing out. +